# Visual studio no termina build de mi codigo c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, build

***Programando en Visual studio 2022, c#, .net framework 4, windows forms.***
La funcionalidad de mi programa es copiar archivos de texto desde una direccion origen hacia una direccion destino.

Al principio no tenía ningún problema ejecutando Start para probar la funcionalidad de mi programa, pero desde ayer cada que hago cambios en mi código e intento ejecutarlo no termina de compilar el código y abrir la aplicación.

[image: Output al intentar compilar el código, build no termina]

Intento cancelar usando "Build > Cancel (ctrl+break)" pero no funciona, se queda igual.

La única forma en que vuelve a funcionar es reiniciando mi computadora, pero si vuelvo a realizar una edición en mi código me vuelve a pasar el mismo problema.

¿Alguna idea de cuál sea la causa y/o solución?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! algun proceso que queda colgado??? es imposible solucionar esto sin mas info, mas que tirando a adivinar...

Comment: El administrador de tareas no me indica que algún proceso esté quedando colgado. Gracias por los consejos, disculpa que no aporte más información, no sé qué más pueda influir en este problema.

Comment: Busca dentro de tu proyecto, y los proyectos asociados/referenciados, y borra las carpetas bin y obj. Luego intenta de nuevo

Comment: Gracias Arriel, lo intenté, pero no me dejaba borrar el archivo "bin\Debug\MyApp.exe", supongo que se quedaba agarrado por algún proceso que no terminaba, pero tampoco quedaba colgado. Al final, logre terminar con los cambios al código y después de publicarlo ya no volví a tener el problema.